# When installing a .msi using powershell - is there a way of pasting in the authentication code for the software within the script?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, windows-installer

The key is always the same. I have it saved in a text document in the same folder as the msi.

A pseudo outline would be:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "H:\Software\Software_x64.msi"

GET "AuthenticationCode" from key.txt

Paste "AuthenticationCode" into SoftwareWindow

NextNextNext Finish
```

Cheers for any assistance

Comment: You are probably looking for something like MSI answer file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't tried it butI think one way is to use msiexec.exe and pass the serial as argument.

```
$mycode = get-content key.txt
msiexec /i "YourMSI.msi" "SERIALNUMBER=$mycode"
```

I found this [link](https://forums.novell.com/showthread.php/212398-Adding-a-MSIEXEC-command-line-argument)

Also have a look at [M$](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/314881)

greets Eldo.Ob